# How to paint outside of selected area in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I just want to know how to paint outside of the selected area with the brush tool without creating multiple layers. Here is my selection:

[image: Selection]

Answer (score 4):

I think you just want to reverse the selection (CMD+SHFT+I) and then paint away. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcut Shift+Ctrl+I on windows And Shift+CMd+i on a mac to avoid destructive editting you can make a new layer and then brush over it.